# Segmentation Fault in X509_STORE_add_lookup()

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program which connects to a remote server and uses a self signed certificate. I get the following errors at a couple of points in the program.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7ec3688 in X509_STORE_add_lookup () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

At this point:

```
    if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(
                ssl_ctx_p, "bundle_test.p12.pem", NULL))
```

And another:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7ec389e in X509_STORE_get_by_subject () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Here:

```
ssl_ret = SSL_connect(ssl_p);
```

I am pretty new to this and do not know what is going wrong, if anybody could suggest a better way to debug or figure out the problem, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Without more context, all I can propose is that you compile all source using `-Wall -Wextra` and fix the code until no more warnings are issued during compilation, then compile with option `-g` and run the app through gdb. This will provide you a detailed backtrace after the crash, where you can also inspect variables.

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't do much work itself. The only thing that can cause a segfault inside this function instead of inside `X509_STORE_load_locations()` is pointer dereference `ctx->cert_store`. Please verify that `ssl_ctx_p` is a valid context and not `NULL`.

```
int SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *CAfile,
                const char *CApath)
        {
        return(X509_STORE_load_locations(ctx->cert_store,CAfile,CApath));
        }
```